# How do I grant execute permissions on a Postgres Routine to a user?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple GRANT statement that I need to run to allow a single user execute permissions on a routine:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ROUTINE sales.refresh_data(varchar, varchar) to rperson
```

...but it's throwing an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sales"
```

From the documentation I can find, this is the correct syntax, and the function signature is correct.

Comment: Check your search path `SHOW search_path;`

Comment: Show search_path returns
sales

Comment: So you don't need all the qualified name, just routine's name on your command.

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "refresh_data"

Comment: Next option according to syntax is routine name incorrect or arg_type incorrect or number of arguments.

Comment: What version are you using?  Are you reading the correct docs the for the version you are using?

Comment: We're running 10.23

Comment: The `routine` key word was apparently introduced in v11 (the documentation has it there, but not in v10). You need to use `procedure`, `function`, or whatever is appropriate for your version.

Comment: Thanks, that worked using the keyword function to grant permissions to a routine.